# Sorting, then re-sorting

Tags: vba, sorting

[image]I am trying to sort the Buy column from Largest to smallest then copy and paste into another column, then I will sort the Sell column from largest to smallest and again copy and paste into another column. The code will not sort, copy/paste, re-sort, then copy/paste; in other words it keeps the original sorting of only the buys. Is there a way to sort the buys, paste them elsewhere, then sort the sells and copy likewise?  I was thinking about trying a do loop but Im not sure why I cant do this in a more simple way.  Any insight would help.  Thank you!

```
' buys

    rows("3:3").Select
        Selection.AutoFilter

    ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("D3" _
        ), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortTextAsNumbers
    With ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
       .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
   End With

   'copy top ten buys
    Range("A5:I14").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("k3").Select
    ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial
    Application.CutCopyMode = False 

' sells
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear  
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("E3" _
        ), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortTextAsNumbers
    With ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

    Range("A5:I14").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("k14").Select
    ActiveSheet.paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: Your use of `Select`, `Selection`, `ActiveSheet` is not necessary, explicitly use the ranges that you have described in your code (e.g. `Range("A5:I14").Copy Range("K3")`. You haven't told us which cells contain your data and how you distinguish between buys and sells.

Comment: you can clear the copy after the paste and clear the sort after the sort.

Comment: Send a pic of the header rows or at least the position of "Buys" and "Sells", this is very doable.

Comment: I am trying to post a PDF image but unsure how...

Comment: Buys are column D and Sells are Column E. The file headers: Trade Date, Plan No, FileSet, Buy Amount, Sell Amount, Net Amount, Buy Shares, Sell Shares, Net  Shares

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only add a new sort key your second sort will be on the Buy *and* the Sell column. Do Sortfields.clear before the second search.